# When I attach sources to jar file in android studio why does it display no executible code found at line

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I open my android project with android studio.  In my libs folder I've a jar file.  When I expand this jar file I open one of the classes file.  I get notification to attach source to this file.  Then I attach source to it and I'm able to see the entire code.  Then I click on attach debugger to android process icon.  When I try to debug the jar which I've attach sources to I always get "no executable code found at line xx" error.  Why is that? I've been struggling with this for few days and I'vent found any solution.